# Unable to setup slurmdbd plugin: Connection refused

Tags: slurm

Unable to setup slurmdbd plugin.

The SLURM installation works fine
Set `AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/slurmdbd` in the `/etc/slurm/slurm.conf`

When I do `sacctmgr` list cluster it gives:

```
sacctmgr: error: slurm_persist_conn_open_without_init: failed to open persistent connection to localhost:6819: Connection refused
sacctmgr: error: slurmdbd: Sending PersistInit msg: Connection refused
sacctmgr: error: Problem talking to the database: Connection refused
```

Comment: Are you running `slurmdbd` as well? Get that working first. Once `sacctmgr` works, then see if the the controller can contact it (`sacctmgr` talks to the slurmdbd directly; it doesn't need the controller active).

Comment: Got it working.
1. If on CentOS 7, use Maria db instead of mysql
2. Ensure these parameters are set into the slurmdbd.conf - /etc/slurm

DbdHost=<in my case same as the slurm controller so : localhost>
DbdPort=6819
SlurmUser=slurm
StorageUser=<user that is to use sacctmgr>
StorageHost=localhost
StoragePass=<password of the user using sacctmgr>
StorageType=accounting_storage/mysql
StorageLoc=slurm_acct_db

3. Grant user access to the slurm databases

Comment: I have the same error, I tried that and it did not work

Comment: it appears that you need to insert some `sleep` statements in between the start of the slurmdbd services and the `sacctmgr` commands to wait for the database connection to actually get started. You can see if the database is *really* available by using the command `netstat -antp | grep LISTEN`; if the database is available you should see an entry such as `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6819            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14200/slurmdbd`